# change dropdown content when checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, html-select

I have made a way to present a droplist to end user and by default containing 4 items `(value=a,value=b,value=c,value=d)`. When a user click on a checkbox the content of the droplist changes to only 2 items `(value=a,value=b)` `IF` unchecked returned to default state.

I achieve this way below using hiding div but wondering if a better different way using Jquery, I have searched and cant figure it out using let say if checked present these options else present default. Currently I have to work with 2 different dropdown which is awkward when passing values in a form.

THE CHECKBOX

```
 <label for="optionChoice"><input class="optionChoice" type="checkbox" id="optionChoice"         name="optionChoice" value="YES" onClick="if(this.c.........
```

*IN MY PHP PAGE I HAVE 2 DIV WHERE ONE IS VISIBLE AND THE OTHER IS NOT ALL DEPENDS ON IF CHECKBOX CLICKED THEN MAKE ONE VISIBLE AND THE OTHER INVISIBLE VISVERSA.*

```
    <div id="test">
           <table class="TableStyle">
            <tr>
             <td>
               <label for="serviceType">Service Type<font color="red"><b> * </b></font></label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select name="serviceType" id="serviceType">
                     <option value="" label="-- Choose One --"> -- Choose One --</option>
                     <option value="A" label="A">A</option>
                      <option value="B" label="B">B</option>
                     <option value="C" label="C">C</option>
                      <option value="D" label="D">D</option>
                </select>
              </td>
           </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
  <div id="test2">
       <table class="TableStyle">
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <label for="serviceType2">Service Type<font color="red"><b> * </b></font></label>
                 </td>
              </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <select name="serviceType2" id="serviceType2">
                        <option value="" label="-- Choose One --"> -- Choose One --</option>
                         <option value="A" label="A">A</option>
                          <option value="B" label="B">B</option>
                      </select>
                   </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
         </div>


    script

        $(function() {
            enable_cbChoice();
            $("#optionChoice").click(enable_cbChoice);
        });
        function enable_cbChoice() {
            if (this.checked) { 
                $("#test").hide();
                $("#test2").show();
            }
            else{
                $("#test").show();
                $("#test2").hide();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to just have one dropdown (id="serviceType") and then add or remove the options based on the state of the checkbox:

```
var detached;
$('#optionChoice').on('change', function() {
    var $el = $(this);

    if( $el.prop('checked') ) {
        detached = $('option[value="C"], option[value="D"]').detach();   
    } else {
       $('#serviceType').append(detached);
    }
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhummel/D43fh/

Comment: THis is amazing, its so simple I feel stupid. Thank You! I will apply this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by detecting the state of the checkbox using javascript. I can show you the method using jquery. Then you can use the remove and append function of jquery to add and remove values from the dropdown. To achieve your problem, you can do something like this.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $("#selectBox option[value='C']").remove();
        $("#selectBox option[value='D']").remove();
    } else {
        $('#selectBox').append('<option value="C">C</option>');
        $('#selectBox').append('<option value="D">D</option>');
    }
});
```